# Why reduction working in one case but not in another case?

Tags: openmp, reduction

Following are the two code snippets where I am working with OpenMP reduction, in the first case (reduction variable `total_num_sp_edges`) every time I get the correct result, but in the second case, different runs deliver different results for the reduction variable (`total_num_splitters`). Would like to know the reason behind the first reduction working but not the second.

First snippet

```
size_t total_num_sp_edges = 0;
...
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:total_num_sp_edges)
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        
        for(auto& sm_t: sm_graph)
        {
            combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid].insert(end(combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid]), sm_t[tid].begin(), sm_t[tid].end());
            std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>().swap(sm_t[tid]);
        }
        
        sort(combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid].begin(), combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid].end(),
        [](const std::pair<int, int>& edge1, const std::pair<int, int>& edge2) {
        return (edge1.first < edge2.first) || (edge1.first == edge2.first && edge1.second < edge2.second);
        });
        
        combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid].erase(unique(combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid].begin(), combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid].end()), combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid].end());
        
        num_thread_local_SpEdges[tid] = combined_thread_local_sm_g[tid].size();
        
        total_num_sp_edges += num_thread_local_SpEdges[tid];
        
    }
```

Second snippet

```
size_t total_num_splitters = 0;
...
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:total_num_splitters)
    {
        std::vector<size_t> local_splitters;
        size_t numThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

        #pragma omp single
        {
            num_thread_local_splitters.resize(numThreads);
            displacements.resize(numThreads);
        }

        if(tid == 0)
        {
            local_splitters.push_back(0);
        }

        #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(size_t i = 1; i < sortedSNData.size(); i++)
        {
            if(comp_afforest[sortedSNData[i]] != comp_afforest[sortedSNData[i-1]])
            {
                local_splitters.push_back(i);
            }   
        }
        
        num_thread_local_splitters[tid] = local_splitters.size();
        total_num_splitters += num_thread_local_splitters[tid];

        #pragma omp single
        {
            splitters.resize(total_num_splitters);
```

Comment: Your second code is incomplete. Could you please correct it? Can you show us the serial code? Your parallelization may be unnecessarily complicated.